# Order of Rate of Growth

Tags: calculus

How would you put these functions in order of rate of growth from the greatest to the smallest?

$f(x) = \log_2 x$, $g(x) = x^x$, $h(x) = x^2 $, $k(x) = 2^x$

I took the derivatives and ended up with

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x\ln(2)}$, $g'(x) = x^x(1 + \ln(x))$, $h'(x) = 2x$, $k'(x) = \ln(2)2^x$

[image: derivative graph]

[Derivative Graph (Desmos)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m98fpg8hqv)

Based on the derivatives, is it necessary for the answer to be put in intervals?

Thanks.

---

The answers I got were (assuming use of intervals)

$(-\infty, -.849)$: $k(x) > f(x) > h(x) > g(x)$

@ x = -.849: $k(x) > f(x) = h(x) > g(x)$

(-.849, 0): $k(x) > h(x) > f(x) > g(x)$

@ x = 0: $k(x) > h(x) > f(x) = g(x)$

(0, .485): $f(x) > k(x) > h(x) > g(x)$

@ x = .485: $f(x) > k(x) = h(x) > g(x)$

(.485, .849): $f(x) > h(x) > k(x) > g(x)$

@ x = .849: $f(x) = h(x) > k(x) > g(x)$

(.849, 1.024): $h(x) > f(x) > k(x) > g(x)$

@ x = 1.024: $h(x) > f(x) = k(x) > g(x)$

(1.024, 1.127): $h(x) > k(x) > f(x) > g(x)$

@ x = 1.127: $h(x) > k(x) > f(x) = g(x)$

(1.127, 1.267): $h(x) > k(x) > g(x) > f(x)$

@ x = 1.267: $h(x) > k(x) = g(x) > f(x)$

(1.267, 1.62): $h(x) > g(x) > k(x) > f(x)$

@ x = 1.62: $h(x) = g(x) > k(x) > f(x)$

(1.62, 3.212): $g(x) > h(x) > k(x) > f(x)$

@ x = 3.212: $g(x)> h(x) = k(x) > f(x)$

$(3.212, \infty)$: $g(x)> k(x) > h(x) > f(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might suppose that the question implies "as $x\rightarrow\infty$", in which case $(3.212, ∞): g(x)>k(x)>h(x)>f(x)$ would be correct.